# Power pack USB problem

Tags: power-supply, usb

I have a power pack with 3 5V outputs, smart usb, 5V 2A usb and 5V 1A usb. My hearing aid charger is 5V 1A. My 250 watt hour power pack shuts off in seconds if I use any of the usb ports regardless of how fully charged the power pack or how depleted my hearing aid is. The power pack does charge my hearing aid charger/hearing aid via the charger's A/C port. My hearing aid charger can hold 2 hearing aids. I have one hearing aid. Is this the reason the power pack will not work with the usb connection? The power pack charges cell phones and laptops via usb. But not my hearing aid charger. Is the power pack faulty? Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Sounds like your battery pack is expecting some minimum load, and shuts off if something is too low of a load. Your hearing aid charger probably only draws a few milliamps.

Comment: In a pinch, you could try plugging another device in to the power pack at the same time in order to keep it awake and charge the hearing aid.

Comment: +1 on what everyone else said. Some power packs can be forced on to mitigate this phenomenon. Most manufacturers don’t bother though.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not faulty.

If the power pack does not see enough load, it will shut down to save power and internal battery from getting empty and damaged.

It is intended to charge a high current device like a mobile phone, and then when mobile phone starts to be full, the current draw drops and the powerpack can shut itself down.

So, your power pack is not suitable for charging low current devices.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest any power packs that I should consider getting?

Comment: No, because I have no knowledge which of the millions of different power packs will work with low currents and which will automatically shut down. Also, asking for suggestions what to buy is not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with others' assessment that the problem is the hearing aid *simply draws too little power for* the charger to realize there is a charging load there.

The solution, however, is to charge something a little bit bigger at the same time.  This thing has 2 ports, right?

By the way, you're not *required* to put any particular load in any particular port.  However, if you plug a 2A device (such as a large tablet) into the 1A port, *it will charge slower* (at the 1A rate).

Answer (score 0):

Your power pack is fine. Just apply some more load to it. A USB fan or LED lamp will be enough, usually. Use a load that does something useful for you, if you can. E.g. in summer perhaps the little fan could prove useful. Or if it's night, you can use the LED light to read by. Or perhaps your phone could be recharged. To provide sufficient load when the phone is fully charged, play a game with heavy 3D graphics :) Or, if you feel particularly wasteful, run one of the [ACID html implementation test suites](https://www.acidtests.org/). Those will typically run the phone's CPU rather hard.

It is rather funny to think that it may take some ACID and a phone to fix your problem...